# Qual é a diferença, na prática, entre Session e Application?

Tags: php, c#, java, session, terminologia

Estou estudando sobre *Tecnologias Web*, e durante minha aula surgiu um tópico sobre conceitos envolvendo `Session` e `Application`. A tecnologia abordada durante a aula foi `C#`. Eu não compreendi muito bem as diferenças entre eles. Pesquisando, encontrei a seguinte resposta:

> A principal diferença entre estes dois conceitos é que o estado da
>   **sessão** armazena variáveis e objetos para um usuário particular e
>   existe enquanto a sessão do usuário existir ao passo que o estado da
>   **aplicação** armazena variáveis e objetos que são compartilhados com
>   todos os usuários da aplicação ao mesmo tempo.

**Fonte:** [ASP.NET 2.0 - Apresentando com o objeto Application](http://www.macoratti.net/07/06/aspn_tas.htm)

Entretanto, não consegui visualizar a aplicabilidade destes conceitos na prática. Alguém poderia elucidar situações onde eu posso aplicar cada uma delas? Estes conceitos se aplicam a outros tipos de tecnologia, tais como `Java`, `PHP`, `Javascript`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você já respondeu metade da pergunta. `Session` é um escopo de configurações para um determinado usuário. `Application` é um escopo de configurações para a aplicação inteira.

Falando do C#, normalmente o registro da aplicação fica num fonte chamado `Global.asax.cs`. Ele faz o registro global de classes, de componentes utilizados e mapeamento primário de aspectos. Recentemente, a Microsoft trocou um pouco de abordagem, usando classes parciais com o nome de `Startup`, mas o princípio é o mesmo.

Em Java a arquitetura de aplicação e sessão não é consensual. Cada fornecedor empacota e distribui a arquitetura de uma forma. Apesar de serem parecidas, não são exatamente compatíveis. O padrão de projeto de uma aplicação para WebSphere é diferente do padrão de um projeto para o JBoss, por exemplo, e normalmente portar de um pro outro demanda uma grande quantidade de configuração e adequações.

> Não consegui visualizar a aplicabilidade destes conceitos na prática. Alguém poderia elucidar situações onde eu posso aplicar cada uma delas?

Ao autenticar um usuário e carregar suas permissões, você utiliza escopo de sessão.

Ao realizar carga de rotas, de configurações de ambiente e de objetos utilizados pela aplicação, como objetos de abstração de bancos de dados (que demandam configuração prévia), você está usando escopo de aplicação.

> Estes conceitos se aplicam a outras tipos de tecnologia, tais como Java, PHP, Javascript?

Sim.

Comment: Apenas para complementar, em ambiente .NET, entre essas aí, existe a Cache, que também possui escopo de aplicação. E é recomendado a não se usar mais Session, veja mais detalhes [neste site](http://eduardopires.net.br/2015/04/pense-duas-vezes-antes-de-utilizar-sessions/).

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Corretíssimo. Desde 2010 dando problema de *Load Balancing*.

Answer (score 8):

**Sessão** é cada usuário conectado a uma aplicação web. Os dados da sessão são úteis quando são individuais ao usuário. Por exemplo, cada usuário logado aqui no fórum tem a sua Sessão.

Um carrinho de compras em uma loja web é armazenado como dado de Sessão pois é individual ao usuário que está acessando.
Quando o navegador/aba é fechado, ou faço logoff esses dados são perdidos.

**Aplicação** é a aplicação web como um todo. Os dados da aplicação são os mesmos para todo mundo. Em um web chat por exemplo os dados são armazenados na aplicação. Todos os usuários logados vêm o mesmo conteúdo.

Mesmo que eu um ou vários usuários façam logoff ou fechem seus navegadores, os dados estarão disponíveis para todos que ainda estão acessando.
Os dados só são perdidos quando o servidor da aplicação é desligado ou alguém exclui esses dados.

---

Sobre utilizar em outras linguagens, é possível sim. Qualquer linguagem de programação web aplicam estes conceitos.

---

**Obs**.: Estes conceitos acima não devem ser confundidos com persistência de dados. Estamos falando de dados na memória (memória RAM do servidor).

Nada impede que os dados sejam armazenados em um banco de dados para consulta posterior.

Comment: Shura16, Os dados da sessão não ficam na memória RAM do cliente. Eles também ficam no servidor, a diferença é que apenas a respectiva sessão tem acesso.

Comment: Em alguns casos sim, por isso citei servidor/cliente.

Comment: Shura16, permanece o fato de que a sua afirmação sobre a Session ser guardada na memória RAM do cliente está incorreta. Aplicacoes WEB mantem estado em varias camadas, entretanto, quando se fala de Application e Session estamos falando de servidor.  O estado de um carrinho de compras, por exemplo, fica no servidor, o que fica no cliente são os cookies (incluindo o ID da sessao) e o estado do próprio browser com as chamadas AJAX, por exemplo, mas isso não é sessão de acordo com o contexto da pergunta. Se a session ficasse na memória RAM do cliente, haveriam vários problemas de segurança.

Comment: Corrigido sobre a questão da memória.

Comment: Ganhou um +1 meu.